# Where can one park one's car for free for a few weeks reasonably close to Seattle (SEA) airport?

Tags: airports, automobiles, seattle, washington-state, sea

I wonder where one can park one's car for free for a few weeks (preferably >1 month) reasonably close to Seattle (SEA) airport.  Let's say reasonably = less than 1h car ride.

Comment: As long as someone lives there you can park it for months in a row in Ballard :)

Comment: @JonathanReez cool, great to know! Does one need a resident parking permit? I'm <1km from Ballard so that'd be convenient if no permit required.

Comment: It was tongue in cheek. There’s a huge homeless RV park there that’s been annoying residents for years

Comment: Why not just leave the car at home?

Comment: And why not use a cheap(ish) parking lot near the airport. Those will be much more secure and work out cheaper than having to replace stolen parts.

Comment: You will not be the first person to try and abuse local parking laws in order to ignore doing the RightThing™, and my gut feeling is that the closer you get to the airport, the more restrictive the laws will be in order to funnel you to the CorrectLocation™.  In addition, if you do find a less restrictive location you will open yourself up to having your car reported abandoned (and potentially towed) by those who actually live there and are aware of their neighbors cars - that will likely be more expensive that the parking fees.

Comment: @PeterM no intent to abuse

Comment: @Willeke typically over 300usd/month

Comment: @KristvanBesien I'm flying home (California).

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt A non-resident treating residential parking as long term storage *is* abuse

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt And top of my google search for "cheap parking near Seatac" has $100/month as the first hit

Comment: @PeterM when I click on those kind of prices, it becomes >300usd/month. Not an abuse to me if the street typically has empty parking slots.

Comment: If it is free and near the airport, railway station, school, hospital or anywhere where parking is both in demand and chargeable, it probably won't have empty parking slots. If such places exist, the locals who know of them aren't going to publish them.

Comment: How about taking public transit to the airport?

Comment: @WeatherVane thanks, 1h driving distance is a large radius that ought to include did areas with plenty of empty parking spaces.

Comment: @DJClayworth that works too

Comment: Backlink to possibly-relevant consequence: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/174509/how-shall-i-proceed-if-my-car-may-contain-illegal-drugs-and-drug-paraphernalia-b

Comment: @Criggie wasn't in Seattle + car was left for 1 day in front of my home. But yes, better leave the car empty!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Seattle's City's Traffic Code does not allow a vehicle to be parked on a city street for longer than 72 hours](https://www.seattle.gov/transportation/projects-and-programs/programs/parking-program/parking-regulations/72-hour-on-street-parking-ordinance). Link to the legal text: [Municipal code 11.72.440](https://library.municode.com/wa/seattle/codes/municipal_code?nodeId=TIT11VETR_SUBTITLE_ITRCO_PT7STSTPALO_CH11.72STSTPARE_11.72.440PAENSEO72HO) "Parking Enforcement; Seventy-two (72) hours."-> one can park up to 72 hours unless posted otherwise.

Perhaps some jurisdiction nearby is more lenient but I'm not aware of it.

Note that the actual enforcement of the 72 hours in Seattle may vary according to the location and neighborhood climate (eg I parked a few hours at night in a public parking spot in West Seattle and the individual living near the parking spot complained: the car would have likely being towed after 72 hours or maybe even before). There's even a dedicated phone line for the Seattle Police 72-Hour Parking Limit/Abandoned Vehicles, (206) 684-8763.