# How can I make sure my car doesn't get impounded/ticketed before the 72h parking deadline in Seattle, or at least, prove it wasn't parked over 72h?

Tags: usa, automobiles, regulations, seattle, washington-state

I'm [reading](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/168799/1810) that there exists a dedicated phone line, 206-684-8763, to report to the Seattle Police vehicles parked in one spot for over 72 hours. How can I make sure that my car doesn't get impounded or ticketed before the 72-hour parking deadline in Seattle, e.g. because of an overzealous citizen or a bored neighbor? E.g., how can I prove, if needs be, that the vehicle wasn't parked for more than 72 hours at the same spot?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about travel, it is about local civic parking policies.

Comment: @GregHewgill parking is 100% on-topic. Cars are used to travel.

Comment: @NateEldredge https://mynorthwest.com/3162800/seattle-reviewing-72-hour-parking-enforcement-policy/ said it got reinstated last April. I'm confused. Anyway, let's assume the law is turned on for the sake of this question.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130285/discussion-on-question-by-franck-dernoncourt-how-can-i-make-sure-my-car-doesnt).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They won't take your neighbors word for it. Instead, they'll have a parking inspector come out to that particular street (they use tiny [Go-4 cars](https://www.flickr.com/photos/southerncalifornian/30556911532)) and take a photo of your car. Then after 72+ hours the parking inspector will come back and take another photo - if your car is still in the exact same spot, you'll get a ticket or get towed away. This is also how they enforce 2/30/120 minute parking limits around the city.

Comment: Is there a camera on that car or does someone have to take a picture manually? [Over here scan cars have roof-mounted cameras](https://nos.nl/artikel/2363617-parkeerboetes-door-scanauto-s-aanvechten-loont) that scan license plates and cross reference the plane number with databases of parking permits and even temporary paid parking.

Comment: @JJJ No fancy camera on the car - just a guy that comes out and takes a photo on a tablet with a special app. They need to give you a physical ticket on the windshield so having an automated car won't pay off.